# Al validar mi datepicker usando Jquery Validate se deforma el icono

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate, bootstrap-datepicker

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy usando *JQuery Validate* para validar mis campos. Hay un problema con el icono del `datepicker` al momento de mostrar el mensaje de que es un campo requerido se deforma el icono que esta agrupado al `input`

El *glyphicon* se agranda al aparecer el mensaje de validación.

```js
function validar() {
  var formDireccionamiento = $("#defaultForm");
  formDireccionamiento.validate({
    errorClass: "mensajeError",
    rules: {
      etaNave: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {

      etaNave: {
        required: "El campo ETA Nave es requerido"
      }
    }
  }).form();

  if (formDireccionamiento.valid()) {
    //Hacer alg
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<link srv="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link srv="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.css" />


<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="etaNave">ETA DE LA NAVE</label>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" id="etaNave" name="etaNave" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Muestro imagen de lo explicado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

librerias js

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/direccionamiento.js"></script>
```

estilos css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sweetalert2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validacion.css">
```

Comment: el problema es el CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/jquery/1.7.2/2628089/ mira haca

Comment: el problema que indico es que se deforma el glyphicon

Comment: es por lo mismo .... que te digo que el problema esta en el CSS; el CSS que estas usando es el por defecto y la validacion te jode el layout... tienes que buscar una css o adaptarto para que no te lo deforme

Comment: En tu HTML no se ve ningún ID que diga `defaultForm`, yo creo te faltó código para tener un [mcve].